# iOS push notification provider hosting

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I understand that for an app to receive notifications, a provider should exist which will maintain a persistent connection to the Apple notification service and send out notifications when required.

I also understand that there are certain requirements that the provider must fulfill such as having the correct certificate and ability to transmit data over a certain port. Considering that I need to create a C# based notification provider that will do this, what is the easiest and relatively cheap way to do this?

Can I write a web service to accomplish this? Do hosts allow you to use your own SSL certificates as required by the provision requirements as mentioned here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

What is the usual way people do this (Individual developers/small dev teams)?

I checked out Urban Airship but I believe that is useful only for marketing messages or other such on demand messages that the developer needs to push to the user.

Comment: Its really not that hard to write your own push notification service so I would suggest going down that route first. There are multiple open source projects in C# just hit up your old friend google. Amazon also offers a PNS http://aws.amazon.com/sns/

Comment: @sbarow: The problem is not in writing it. The issue is with the infrastructure requirements for hosting such a service.

Comment: Amazons push notification service might be a good bet then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend https://www.parse.com. It's working fairly well for me. I downloaded the tutorial and in 30 minutes I was sending and reciving push notifications.

If you don't like parse's service, try another one, but I would advise you against trying to set up your own server. These services are made to make it easier and faster to develop, and they are really worth it.

Comment: Well, I discovered Parse after posting this question so that's what I am using now. I would recommend it too.